# Diferença entre RequestMapping e PostMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estava dando uma olhada em requisições do `Spring Boot` e vi que dá para fazer uma requisição `POST`, de duas formas:

```
//primeira forma
@RequestMapping(value = "/dev", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> dev(@RequestParam("nome") String nome) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(nome, HttpStatus.OK);
}

//segunda forma
@PostMapping("/dev")
    public ResponseEntity<String> nome(@RequestParam("nome") String nome) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(nome, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Testei com o `Postman` e ambas retornam o mesmo resultado.

- Qual a diferença dessa duas formas?
- Existe alguma limitação em alguma das duas?
- Qual a mais adequada, quando vai enviar dados de um formulário, por
  exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RequestMapping` é a anotação utilizada tradicionalmente para implementar URL handler, ela suporta os métodos Post, Get, Put, Delete e Pacth.

`@PostMapping` é uma maneira mais simples de implementar URL handler da anotação `@RequestMapping` com o método Post. Na implementação de `@PostMapping` ele é anotado com `@RequestMapping` especificando o método Post, pode ser visto no [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html):

```
@Target(value=METHOD)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @RequestMapping(method=POST)
public @interface PostMapping
```

Outras tipos de requisições também tem formas mais simples: `@GetMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@DeleteMapping` e `@PatchMapping`, todas utilizam internamente a anotação `@RequestMapping`, especificando o tipo de requisição.

Não existe uma limitação de uma forma ou outra, apenas na segunda forma você não precisa especificar o tipo de requisição, pois a própria anotação especifica, tendo assim uma sintaxe mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Ambas fazem o mesmo trabalho. A diferença é que `@PostMapping` faz parte de um grupo predefinido de anotações compostas que internamente usam `@RequestMapping`. Essas anotações funcionam como atalhos que servem para simplificar o mapeamento dos métodos HTTP e expressar de forma mais concisa os métodos de manipulação. A vantagem das anotações compostas é no aspecto semântico, pois com elas o código fica mais limpo e de fácil leitura.